# How to convert a JSON file to a readable object in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I have the following .json file with the following kind of contents:

```json
{
  "res": [
    {
      "test1": "323dfer",
      "test2": "adqdcr2c"
    },
    {
      "test1": "23cr2c2c",
      "test2": "23rv2rvc"
    }
  ]
}
```

And currently I am accessing this file like so:

```java
InputStream jsonfile= this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.json");

assert jsonfile!= null;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map jsonMap = mapper.readValue(jsonfile, Map.class);

Object records = jsonMap.get("res");
System.out.println(records);
```

which results in this output:

```
[{test1=323dfer, test2=adqdcr2c}, {test1=23cr2c2c, test2=23rv2rvc}]
```

However, I am now not sure how to access the second object in the array and loop trough the keys, e.g. test1 and test2, etc.

I am wondering if anyone can help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Records is probably also a Map, so cast to Map and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should create an entity.

Like below:

```
private class TestObject{
public String testName;

public TestObject(String testName) {
    this.testName= testName;
}
```

}

Second: You should add Google GSON (Maven) dependency. Its very usefull library. You can use this [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson).

Finally: Create a Gson object then call its convertion method.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

TestObject testObject = gson.fromJson(jsonfile, TestObject.class);
System.out.println(testObject.testName);
```